# Can two equivalent types be declared to be incompatible?

Tags: typescript, types, incompatibility, nominal-typing

I have some equivalent types that represent unique Ids:

```
type FlanId = string;
type BranId = string;
```

While these are actually the same type under the hood. I would like for them to be incompatible with each other.

So this should be ok:

```
f: FlanId = "43492393"
b: BranId = "05903242"
```

but then

```
f = b
```

should throw a typescript error.

Is this possible?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate question but I’m on mobile now so I can’t search effectively.

Comment: I tried searching for "typescript and nominal" and came up with a few results. Thanks @jcalz